# how to apply multiple conditions according to the counter and give output for each condition in excel using pandas and python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, python-2.7

Given input table:

```
schedule actual dev count rate
1235     1233   -2         235
1236     1222   -14        235
1255     1113   -142       235
1244     1242   -2         235
1239     1212   -27        235
1856     1500   -356       235
1356     1220   -136   1   235
1478     1520    42        235
1563     1623    60        235
1235     1350    115       235
1294     1432    138       235
1278     1650    372       235
1913     2000    87        235
1650     1750    100    2  235
```

In this table there are 4 columns dev stands for deviations which is simply the difference between "actual" and "schedule" columns. Next we have "count" column in which number is incremented after every 7 consecutive -(ve) or + (ve) dev and in the last we have a "rate" column

Now, my goal is to calculate the penalty for that incremented counter value only and put zero everywhere else and I really want to know where I am making mistake and I don't want these values in a excel format, I need those values in a List or Array form . So that I can use them further.

My attempt:

```
counts = df['count'].values.tolist()
devs = df['dev'].values.tolist()
rates = df['rate'].values.tolist()
sustained = []

for i, j, k in zip(counts, devs, rates):
    if j > 0:  #when dev is positve
        if 5>= i > 0:  #when number of counts are between 1 to 5
            sus = abs(j) * k * 0.075
            sustained.append(sus)
        else:
            sustained.append(0)

        if 10>= i > 5:   #when number of counts are between 6 to 10 
            sus = abs(j) * k * 0.125
            sustained.append(sus)
        else:
            sustained.append(0)

        if i > 10:  #when number of counts are above 10
            sus = abs(j) * k * 0.25
            sustained.append(sus)
        else:
            sustained.append(0)

    else:    #when dev is negative
        if 5 >= i > 0: #when number of counts are between 1 to 5
            sus = abs(j) * k * 0.075
            sustained.append(sus)
        else:
            sustained.append(0)

        if 10 >= i > 5 and j < 0: #when number of counts are between 5 to 10
            sus = abs(j) * k * 0.125
            sustained.append(sus)
        else:
            sustained.append(0)

        if 10>= i > 5: #when number of counts are above 10
            sus = abs(j) * k * 0.2
            sustained.append(sus)
        else:
            sustained.append(0)

#df['penalty'] = pd.Series(sustained)
#df
```

print("count: ", counts)
print("sustained penalties: ", sustained)  #sustained stands for penalties

output:

```
("count: ", , , , , , , 1, , , , , , , 2)
("sustained penalties: ", 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
```

desired output:

```
    count: 0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,2
sustained penalties: 0,0,0,0,0,0,2397,0,0,0,0,0,0,1762.5
```

i need those penalties values in the form of a list or array, so that I can use them for further use that's why I comment out pandas's code to calculate those.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can do:

```
s = (pd.cut(df['count'], 
           bins=[0,5,10,np.inf], 
           labels=[0.075, 0.125, 0.25])
      .astype(float)
      .fillna(0)
    )

df['penalty'] = s * df['rate'] * df['dev'].abs()
```

Output:

```
    schedule  actual  dev  count  rate  penalty
0       1235    1233   -2    NaN   235      0.0
1       1236    1222  -14    NaN   235      0.0
2       1255    1113 -142    NaN   235      0.0
3       1244    1242   -2    NaN   235      0.0
4       1239    1212  -27    NaN   235      0.0
5       1856    1500 -356    NaN   235      0.0
6       1356    1220 -136    1.0   235   2397.0
7       1478    1520   42    NaN   235      0.0
8       1563    1623   60    NaN   235      0.0
9       1235    1350  115    NaN   235      0.0
10      1294    1432  138    NaN   235      0.0
11      1278    1650  372    NaN   235      0.0
12      1913    2000   87    NaN   235      0.0
13      1650    1750  100    2.0   235   1762.5
```

Comment: I am sorry but now I edited my question. Actually I need those penalties values inside a list or array , so that i can use them further. Please can you tell me where I making mistake inside my code, I really want to apply those condition to calculate those penalties.